# How to cluster direction of traffic data?

Tags: classification

I have data on many trips (same route). The trip content: `latitude`, `longitude`, and `time at bus stop`. I want to detect the trips that are in the same direction (will have to be two clusters: same direction and opposite direction). Is there an algorithm that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

In way, the algorithm depends on what implementation you want to do specifically.

You have the starting point (X,Y) and ending point (A,B). This forms a vector that has a certain slope, say m. Any vector that is parallel to it has the same slope m and can be considered as going same direction/opposite direction. Same direction can be detected by looking at the sign of the difference between starting/ending co-ordinates.